# tfs 2012 failed to run test case: Error calling Initialization method for test class

Tags: mtm

Recently we found our integration test failed unexpected with following exception:

We even remeber that we have changed nothing to TFS BDT workflow and test case.

Error exception:

> Error calling Initialization method for test class
>   UITestDemo.UITestDemo01:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: To
>   run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test
>   agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How
>   to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the
>   Desktop" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012) If you are
>   running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the
>   build agent to run as an interactive process. For more information,
>   see "How to: Configure and Run Scheduled Tests After Building Your
>   Application" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254735)

Error Stack Trace:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize()
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestExtensionExecution.BeforeTestInitialize(Object
>   sender, BeforeTestInitializeEventArgs e)
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecution.RaiseBeforeTestInitialize(BeforeTestInitializeEventArgs
>   args)
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunInitializeMethod()

We have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, we found that test is running by account: **"computerName$"** on environment, not the specified account in test controller settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SystemInformation>
  <ComputerName>ComputerName</ComputerName>
  <UserName>ComputerName$</UserName>
  <UserDomainName>WORKGROUP</UserDomainName>
  <OSInfo>
    <OSName>Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise </OSName>
    <OSVersion>Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1</OSVersion>
    <SystemDirectory>C:\Windows\system32</SystemDirectory>
    <SystemLocale>English (United States)</SystemLocale>
    <UserLocale>English (United States)</UserLocale>
  </OSInfo>
  <ProcessorInfo>
    <Processor0>
      <ProcessorName>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v2 @ 3.00GHz</ProcessorName>
      <ProcessorFamily>Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4</ProcessorFamily>
      <ProcessorSpeed>2999</ProcessorSpeed>
    </Processor0>
    <Error>NoError</Error>
  </ProcessorInfo>
  <MemoryInfo>
    <TotalPhysicalMemory>4945</TotalPhysicalMemory>
    <AvailablePhysicalMemory>1541</AvailablePhysicalMemory>
    <MemoryLoad>68</MemoryLoad>
    <TotalVirtualMemory>2047</TotalVirtualMemory>
    <AvailableVirtualMemory>1432</AvailableVirtualMemory>
    <Error>NoError</Error>
  </MemoryInfo>
  <ScreenInfo>
    <ScreenHeight>768</ScreenHeight>
    <ScreenWidth>1024</ScreenWidth>
    <BitsPerPixel>32</BitsPerPixel>
  </ScreenInfo>
  <IEInfo>
    <IEVersion>11.0.9600.16428</IEVersion>
    <Error>NoError</Error>
  </IEInfo>
</SystemInformation>
```

Solution:
We open the using test settings in MTM test settings manager.
And recheck each environment should run test on correct role.

Then retest run pass.